# ows_Url Undefined - SPServices

Tags: spservices

I am using `SPServices` `GetListItems` method to retrieve items from a document library and show them on the screen. So far I am able to get the Title of the items and append them to a `div` on the page. The problem is when I try to get the URL of the item, it returns `Undefined`. Here is the code I am using:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "News",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Url' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var href = ($(this).attr("ows_Url"));
            var title = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
            var liHtml = "<p><a href='" + href + "'>" + title + "</a></p>";
            $("#content").append(liHtml);
        });
    }
});
```

After researching the issue myself, I read that `ows_Url` is a managed property and I *think* it may not be retrievable? Is this correct? If this is the case, how can I get this URL attribute?

Comment: Do you need the URL of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a document library, you'd want to use the ows_FileRef field to pull the URL of the file. This will get you a value like, `/managedpath/site/library/filename.jpg`, which is what I think you're after here.

Answer (score 1):

Document library does not have any `URL` column unless you create custom one. I think your requirement is to get the the `URL` and `Title` of documents. In document library there is a hidden column named `FileRef`. It stores document's relative path like

```
/yourSiteUrl/YourLibraryNam/FileName.Extension
```

So your `CAMLViewFields` should look like following

```
"<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
    <FieldRef Name='FileRef' />
</ViewFields>"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also correct and very helpful. Eric's answer was first so I marked his as the answer. I do appreciate the help though!

Comment: It's ok. Try this Chrome tool for building CAML https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/camljs-console/ohjcpmdjfihchfhkmimcbklhjdphoeac?hl=en